# HP DL380 Gen7 - Debian 11 - lscpu doesn't show the right number of CPUs/cores

Tags: debian, cpu

I'm actually trying to figure out a strange Debian output about my system. I recently purchased a HP DL380 gen7 with 2 CPUs (xeon X5690) and 6 cores / 12 threads per CPU. But, while doing `lscpu` it returns this :

```
lscpu
Architecture :                          x86_64
Mode(s) opératoire(s) des processeurs : 32-bit, 64-bit
Boutisme :                              Little Endian
Tailles des adresses:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Processeur(s) :                         1
Liste de processeur(s) en ligne :       0
Thread(s) par cœur :                    1
Cœur(s) par socket :                    1
Socket(s) :                             1
Nœud(s) NUMA :                          2
Identifiant constructeur :              GenuineIntel
Famille de processeur :                 6
Modèle :                                44
Nom de modèle :                         Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5690  @ 3.47GHz
Révision :                              2
Vitesse du processeur en MHz :          2433.274
Vitesse maximale du processeur en MHz : 3466,0000
Vitesse minimale du processeur en MHz : 1600,0000
[...]
```

So I did further investigations and used `dmidecode -t 4 | grep -E 'Socket Designation|Count'`
it returns :

```
        Socket Designation: Proc 1
        Core Count: 6
        Thread Count: 12
        Socket Designation: Proc 2
        Core Count: 6
        Thread Count: 12
```

So does anyone know what's going on here ? Debian does it really take care of all my CPUs/cores/threads or should I tweak stuff ?

Comment: something looks wrong.  run `grep processor /proc/cpuinfo `.  That will show you the full number of processors that the kernel is using.  If it isn't what you are expecting, you could be limiting the number of kernels for some reason.  check /proc/cmdline, check bios settings, and check the kernel boot up messages (if you have systemd you can run `journalctl  -k | grep CPU` )

Comment: The output from dmidecode seems to match your hardware description; it's possible that `lscpu` doesn't do the right thing on your system (for whatever reason). But toppk's grep should tell you the number of "logical" CPUs (taking into account hyperthreading) ... and another tool to consider is `lshw` ... `sudo lshw -c processor`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tips from @toppk and @tink, I finally found the solution: for whatever reason, the APIC was disabled in BIOS.

Following [a blog post](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1125/debian-11-bullseye-boot-freeze-kernel-panic-hp-proliant-dl380), I also solved some other boot issues.

HP default BIOS and Linux kernel seem to fight on a bunch of points and tweaking stuff is a bit tricky but I finally get a system booting correctly, and Debian now perfectly recognizes and uses my 24 cores.